# python construct string with var

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have following dict, where `Incoming Inspection Report` is the table name.

```
querystring = {"q":"Select * from \"Incoming Inspection Report\"","format":"json","headers":"true","metadata":"true","arrays":"false","page":"1","per_page":"20000"}
```

how can I construct the `querystring` dynamically for multiple tables ?
I tried `.format` string,

```
table_name = 'Incoming Inspection Report'
querystring = '{"q":"Select * from \"{table}\"","format":"json","headers":"true","metadata":"true","arrays":"false","page":"1","per_page":"20000"}'.format(table=table_name)
```

but didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "parameterize?"  Where are you trying to use this dict/string/query?  What query are you trying to run?  Also, you should enclose table names in SQL queries in backticks, not quotes.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: You want to `.format()` the string that **contains the placeholder**, not some other string. To understand what's happening, build the query string first: `qstr = "...".format(...)`, and _then_ put it in the dictionary `querystring = {"q": qstr, "format": "json", ...}`. Now replace `qstr` with the right side of the `=` in that line if you want to do everything in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using f-strings?

```
table_name_1 = 'Incoming Inspection Report'
querystring1 = {"q":f"Select * from \"{table_name_1}\"","format":"json","headers":"true","metadata":"true","arrays":"false","page":"1","per_page":"20000"}

table_name_2 = 'Table name 2'
querystring2 = {"q":f"Select * from \"{table_name_2}\"","format":"json","headers":"true","metadata":"true","arrays":"false","page":"1","per_page":"20000"}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the below is what you are looking for

```
table_name = 'my_table'
querystring = {"q": f"Select * from {table_name}", "format": "json", "headers": "true",
               "metadata": "true", "arrays": "false", "page": "1", "per_page": "20000"}

print(querystring.get('q'))
```

output

```
Select * from my_table
```

Comment: At least the other answer tells the asker what this fancy `f"...{var_name}..."` construct is called. "This is what you're looking for" is a poor explanation of your answer when OP doesn't seem to know the term they're looking for (string interpolation)